# Giving images 360 view in html5 canvas after dynamic selection..(kineticjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs, 360-degrees

Is there any way I can make an image 3d..like give it a 360 degree view in html5 canvas.
I looked at some plugins like jquery reel .but they are not enough for the functionality m looking for..
I have created a type of visual studio ..where user first selects an image and then add graphic and then add text..
now what I want is after all this user should be able to rotate the assembled elements and see a 360 view..
I have all the images I need to give it a 360 view but don't know how I'm supposed to go about it.
any help appreciated..

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reel should be able to do this for you, but you need to have the server dynamically write the images, or change the address in reel for where your images are located.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this what you need: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example15.php 
In this implementation you can choose a directory with images and it will show you 360 or 3D view.

Comment: I have seen this..But the images are static in these examples..I'm looking for dynamic image fetch which is not supported by ajax-zoom

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it without using CSS3 then you have to go with WebGL.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/webgl/part-3-html5-canvas-webgl-with-three-js/

Three.js is poorly documented thus you have to make sure you have prior knowledge about 3d graphics.

Comment: I don't have any 3d knowledge..and all the webgl three.js examples are using static contents...I want content to be dynamic..I don't actually need webgl or 3d in html5 canvas..I can also make use of some css 360 degree rotation plugins..but m having trouble..hiding the data in background for the 3d view..It's tough to explain here..